# ExtJS 6.02 - Is it possible to attach a mouseleave event to an Ext.menu.Item?

Tags: javascript, extjs, mouseleave

When a user's cursor leaves an Ext.menu.Item (by mousing off the menu dropdown), I would like to remove the 'x-menu-item-active' class from the last mouse overed menu item.

Currently this does not automatically occur in Ext 6.0.2 i.e., when a user mouses out from an Ext.menu, the last menu item that the user hovered over still contains the 'x-menu-item-active' class.

Currently I am accomplishing this this way:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.someController', {

    init: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.control({

             '#idOfMyMenu': {
                   mouseleave: me.onMouseLeave
             }
        });

    },

    onMouseLeave: function(target) {
        var me = this,
            activeCls = 'x-menu-item-active',
            menuItems = target.items;

        Ext.each(menuItems, function(item) {
            if (item.hasCls(activeCls)) {
                item.removeCls(activeCls);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, this requires looping over all the menu items in my dropdown menu everytime a user mouses out. Is there anyway I can attach a 'mouseleave' listener to a Ext.menu.Item specifically so that I don't need to loop over all the menu items?

The Ext.menu.Item class only contains 'blur', 'focusleave' events which do not allow me to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid looping but you can hide it behind the DOM API if you think it looks cleaner...

```
onMouseLeave: function(menu, ev){
    Ext.fly(ev.getTarget())
        .down('.x-menu-item-active')
        .removeCls('x-menu-item-active');
}
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lpo)

Otherwise there are no mouse events on the out-of-the-box Ext menu items, you'd have to implement your own custom component.